# Geometry Problem Solving Question

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, word-problem, pythagorean-triples

I am struggling with this question where I don't know how to use my knowledge on Pythagoras theorem and trigonometry to work out the missing length.

[image]

Thank You and help is appreciated

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Along with question you should also show your effort.

Comment: Now slowly find the lwngths of $BC,BM, BM, $ etc. where $M$ is foot of perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try applying similarity or equating $\tan c$ in both triangles.

More Hints:

$1$: Find $BC$ using Pythagoras Theorem.

$2$: Then find $\tan c$ for both triangles and equate, you will get $CD$.

With Similarity:
Notice in $\triangle EDC$  and $\triangle ABC$
$\angle DCE = \angle BCA and \angle EDC = \angle ABC = 90$
$\triangle DCE ~ \triangle BCA$ by AA similarity
Now, $\cfrac {ED}{DC} = \cfrac{AB}{BC}$ And you can get $BC$ by applying pythagoras theorem.

Comment: Do i look at the scale factor

Comment: @user123456 i have added more hints, do check those and try again.  
If that helps then accept the answer.  
Thanks

Comment: um this is from a non calculator exam

Comment: You don't need a calculator, in $\triangle ABC \tan C = \cfrac{AB}{BC}$ and in $\triangle CED \tan C =\cfrac{ED}{CD}$ , just equate these two fractions to get CD

Comment: i haven't learned about the sin c method yet in school

Comment: Ok, so have you studied similarity of triangles?

Comment: yes I have studied similarity

Comment: @user123456 i have added my solution with similarity

Comment: i found that DC is 16/3

Comment: would that be correct

Comment: @user123456 yes, $DC = \cfrac {16}{3} is correct$  
If this answer helped you, Please accept the answer.
Thanks

Comment: idk why on the mark scheme it says 14/3

Comment: but i think we are right with 16/3

Comment: so thank you very much for helping me

Comment: one more thing please can you upvote the question as I would like to ask more questions in the future and if I get limited for answering questions I can't ask any more questions. Thank You

Comment: Begging for reputation is not the way to go @user123456

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the pythagorean theorem, $BC=8$.

And $\triangle BCA$ is similar to $\triangle DCE$ due to $AA$ (Angle-Angle) Similarity.

Look at $DE$. It is similar to $AB$.

Hint: One triangle has sides $\dfrac 32$ times greater than the other.

Comment: um do I find the scale factor

Comment: Yes, one triangle has sides $\dfrac 32$ greater than the other. @user123456

Comment: um as BC is 8cm would the scale factor from BC to DC be 2 as 4cm to 8cm is x2 scale factor?

Comment: oh nvm i didn't realise you had to flip the other triangle too

Comment: now do I do 8cm / 3/2 to work out length

Answer (score 0):

Using the law of sines, you know that:
$$\sin C=\frac6{10}$$
And since $C$ is common to $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle EDC$, then $EC$ can be solved as:
$$\sin C=\frac{4}{EC}\Rightarrow EC=\frac4{\sin C}=\frac4{\frac6{10}}=\frac{40}6$$
And using the pythagorean theorem, we can now solve for $DC$:
$$DC^2=EC^2-4^2$$
$$DC=\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{40}6\biggr)^2-4^2}=\sqrt{\frac{256}9}=\frac{16}3$$
$$\therefore AD=8-DC=8-\frac{16}3=\frac83$$